# Tag Request for [google-document]

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, tag-creation

I've searched the tags on SO for a [google-document] tag, but couldn't find one. The closest is probably the [google-docs](/questions/tagged/google-docs) tag. Here people will go wrong if they choose that one. Not only is it replaced by [google-drive](/questions/tagged/google-drive), it is meant to resemble the office suite of Google in the Cloud.

Given the high number of questions on Google Documents and the very high number of [google-apps-script](/questions/tagged/google-apps-script) question, that very often use [google-spreadsheet](/questions/tagged/google-spreadsheet) or [google-document], I'm in favor of creating that particular tag.

The list below, I was able to tag as a [google-document]. These were only taken from the first search page: https://stackoverflow.com/search?page=1&tab=relevance&q=google%20document

List

- [autoCrat naming google documents](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13424252/1536038)
- [Manipulate PositionedImage and wrap text around image in a Google Document](https://stackoverflow.com/q/20274302/1536038)
- [Google Document - Background Color](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11106131/1536038)
- [google apps specify path for created document](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14265970/1536038)
- [Any way to Format or Write code in Google Document](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1817616/1536038)
- https://stackoverflow.com/q/6269826/1536038
- [Export Excel file or Google Document from Android](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11815866/1536038)
- [How to copy graphs to a document using google script](https://stackoverflow.com/q/20103036/1536038)
- [Any way to Format or Write code in Google Document](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1817616/1536038)
- https://stackoverflow.com/q/6269826/1536038
- [Google Script openById don't work?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13156230/1536038)
- [Google Script openById don't work?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13156230/1536038)
- [DocumentApp.getActiveDocument() returns null](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13440938/1536038)

edit:
Tag is deleted by: https://stackoverflow.com/users/168868/charles. Perhaps he can delete the [google-spreadsheet](/questions/tagged/google-spreadsheet) tag as well. I'm out.

Comment: Could you compile a list of potential candidates for the tag?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=google-document

Comment: ... is it just me or does that search turn up a particularly weak set of posts to make your case? Perhaps select a couple you really think need that particular tag.

Comment: [301 results](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%22google+document%22) using the exact words "google+document"

Comment: @bart 37000 hits, I find hardy weak. If 10 percent were to yield a google document, then were talking about 3700 questions. I will edit my question, to have a list.

Comment: 37000 hits the first ones of which already hit upon a random combination of "Google" and "documentation". We're not trying to be annoying, but the better you make your case, the quicker we can do what you propose.

Comment: @JoshC Sorry for being direct: No. [google-documents] would be a synonym.

Answer (score 2):

Google Documents are provided by the service called Google Docs, which is covered under [google-docs](/questions/tagged/google-docs) and [google-docs-api](/questions/tagged/google-docs-api).

Google Docs are now files that live under Google Drive.  Google Drive is completely covered under [google-drive](/questions/tagged/google-drive).

There's also directly related tags like [google-apps-script](/questions/tagged/google-apps-script), a scripting interface for all Google Docs document types.

If we attempt to add [google-document](/questions/tagged/google-document), we'd have to come up with a way to positively differentiate it and [google-docs](/questions/tagged/google-docs) when people select a tag.  Given that we have undeniable proof that people ignore tag wiki excerpts, we're going to have people picking [google-document](/questions/tagged/google-document) when they mean [google-docs](/questions/tagged/google-docs) and all hell is going to break loose.

Further, given the relatively low volume of questions in the various Docs/Drive related tags, we probably do not need a tag dedicated to Documents.  It seems that the only Doc type that has a separate tag is [google-spreadsheets](/questions/tagged/google-spreadsheets) -- and it nearly has more questions than all of the Docs & Drive tags combined!

In conclusion, **adding this tag would only create confusion**.  It should not exist.  If it has to exist, then we should find a different, *unambiguous* name for it, and then also rename the Spreadsheets tag for consistency.  That said, [google-docs-document](/questions/tagged/google-docs-document) doesn't exactly roll off the tongue...

Also, if anyone from Google is reading this, *why* did you give your word processor a name that has a horrible naming collision with the parent service?  It's almost as bad as the WinRT / Windows RT fiasco, only at a mere fraction of the scale.  I'm already policing [windows-rt](/questions/tagged/windows-rt) as it is...

Comment: 1) The [google-spreadsheet] tag has been around for almost three years. That's not a fair comparison !!
 
2) Only recently, the Apps Script Developer Relations team, introduced the [google-apps-script] functionality into Google Documents. Many more questions can be expected to have these combinations.

The scripts themselves are also part of the [google-drive], and yet the tag exists. Where were you back then?
Why don't you make the [google-docs] a synonym of the [google-drive]?